# Cannot get theme to work on catalog view

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, magento, themes

I have theme i am trying to get work on a remote server that works fine on my local copy.  This is for magento 1.4.1.1.  On the working local copy I have 'theme144' within the 'base' package, there are 3 store views; .  In the admin there are 3 design change(System>Design), one for each store view.  These are the only changes i see in the admin pertaining to design.  When testing the site on the remote server, the correct templates are being used for everything except the catalog view. Magento reverts to the 'default' theme inside the 'base' package. All the images, and it seems like the templates, are all using the other theme.

I've tried specifying the theme explicitly in System>Configuration>Design for the Skin, Layout, and Templates, even though on the working local copy these are not set.  This got magento to find the images and style sheets, but it was still using 'default' for the templates.

At this point i don't where else to look to give me hints as to why this is happening.  I eliminated all the differences between the local and remote site, both in the admin and the template file structure.

**edit**: This issue also extends to the product detail view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a reported bug in Magento.  Apparently if you apply the design change to a store that is not the 'All store views'(like the local machine view), then the design changes wont propagate properly.  If this occurs, the you can get Magento apply the updated design by selecting the template in the 'Custom Design' tab on the root category(make sure to apply changes to child elements as well). I reverted these changes and the theme finally stuck.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/35761/

Answer (score 1):

On the remote server check each category's design tab to see if it has a theme set there, that would override the other settings.

Comment: I have checked this; there are no custom design parameters set for either the categories or the products on the local copy